# MVVM - Ctor fails : Specified element is already the logical child of another element | WPF

Tags: wpf, mvvm, user-controls, parent-child

I know there are answers to **"Specified element is already the logical child of another element"** problem but this one is weird.

I have two view models; parent being say `ParentVM` and child being `ChildVM`.

In `ParentVM`, I create and display a user control with `DataContext=ChildVM`. And in **ChildVM's constructor** I had a code like this:

```
if(somecondition)
{
    Xceed.Wpf.Toolkit.MessageBox.Show("sth");
}
```

When this `MessageBox.Show()` method is executed, the error happens. Then I moved this code from constructor to a command and the problem disappeared.

What is the cause of this? Although the problem seems disappeared I want to know why it is solved when the code was moved out of constructor (Initialization of visual components?)

Thanks.

Comment: what happens if you use the wpf messagebox? and btw why you call messagebox.show() in a constructor?

Comment: You're creating and displaying UI components from your VM? You're doing it wrong.

Comment: @blindmeis, same error with the standard messagebox. I actually moved the code from ctor but just wondering why the problem occured.

Comment: @kentBoogaart, Nope, I just create and select the VM and it is shown with related user control through resolution.

Comment: @Mert: I misread your "I create and display a user control". However, you're still displaying message boxes from your VM, which amounts to the same thing.

Comment: @KentBoogaart, I should've been more clear but actually I have an interface called IMessager and an implementation Messager for that interface that calls Xceed.Wpf.Toolkit.MessageBox.Show("sth"). I don't know a better pattern to follow, if you do please let me know. Thanks.